# How to do Kerberos client authentication .Net api 7.1

Tags: solace

I am using solace as middle-ware for client and server communication.
I want to move from none to kerberos authentication.

Servers are unix and already configured for kerberos authentication.
Client is .Net desktop gui application. And there are be multiple users.

I have some question regarding client kerberos authentication.

1. Do we need keytab file to connect to server and keytab file should be common for all users Or keytab file should be create with each users credentials.
2. What if the password changes?
3. Do we need to ask users to install java to get kinit or krb5?
4. What are the setting/configuration required on client side?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

You do need to add a keytab to Solace's /keytabs directory. To configure the keys from the keytab tab to Solace's registered key table after the file has been added, enter the following Kerberos Keytab Authentication CONFIG CLI command:

```
solace(config-kerberos keytab)# add-keytab <keytab-filename> <index>
```

The number of keytab files is completely dependent on your setup. Typically, there will one keytab file per IP address that is common for all users but if your setup requires greater control, you can add up to a total of 48 keytabs.

When you change your Kerberos password, you will need to recreate and re-add all your keytabs.

The client-side API requirements for a client to use Kerberos authentication do include using the appropriate Java distribution or installed Kerberos libraries for the messaging API that is used. For .NET applications, the SSPI that is distributed with Windows is used, so Java is not required.

A client application must also set the authentication scheme to Kerberos for the respective session. In .NET, this is done with the *SessionProperties.AuthenticationSchemeKRB* session property. You can also set the Service Principle Name with the *Session.Properties.KRBServiceName* session property.

Comment: Thanks Alexandra for reply.
Still I have following doubts:

Comment: Thanks Alexandra for reply!
Still I have following doubts:

1. Where to run the CONFIG CLI command. It's not working on windows command prompt.
2. Can we set keytab file path name programmatically instead of above command? As we set the principle name programmatically.
3. I guess if password changes then we can handle it using kinit process. Is there anything extra required for it?
4. I have got win xp and I dint find file krb5.ini on c:\winnt

Comment: You will need to ssh directly to Solace or use SolAdmin to apply the key. For more information about this, please refer to the Solace Router Feature Provisioning Guide available on the Solace Dev Portal. In this guide, you will find instructions on using the CLI (https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Router_Feature_Provisioning/Using_the_Solace_Router_CLI.html), and more information on configuring Kerberos (https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Router_Feature_Provisioning/Managing_Client_Authentication_and_Authorization.html).

Comment: The keytab file path cannot be set programmatically on the Solace Router and must exist in Solace's file system. When you change the password, you will have to recreate/add the keytab and issue a new TGT with kinit. If the krb5.ini file is not located in the c:\winnt directory, it might be located in c:\windows.

Comment: Hi Alexandra,

I have windows desktop gui application (xp and win7 compatible) which uses .net solace api 7.1.

How can I set the following

Comment: Hi Alexandra,

I have windows desktop gui application (xp and win7 compatible) which uses .net solace api 7.1.

How can I set the CONFIG CLI command, I can't ask user to run this command manually on CLI before installing/running application.
Is it for registry setting on client machine that I can do set pragmatically or is it for Router/Server setting which required on our server/unix machine?

I have both win7 and xp users. There is no "c:\windows" dir on xp. I am using xp as development machine and xp's "c:\winNT" dindn't have krb5.ini

Comment: The keytab file must be added to the Solace appliance or VMR, so this step requires access to the Solace appliance or VMR. This step is unrelated to the client applications and is required for the initial setup of Kerberos authentication on Solace. The keytab is not required on the application side. I suggest creating a separate StackOverflow post for your Windows XP question using the 'kerberos' and 'windows-xp' tag in order to find the help you need, as this is unrelated to Solace and the original question.